# How to use AnyEvent::HTTP to get only part of the page?

Tags: perl, anyevent

It is necessary to read only part of the page (n bytes) and close the connection, how to do this on AnyEvent::HTTP ?

Comment: It looks like ikegami's answer is almost certainly what you're looking for, but it's worth pointing out that the 'Range' feature is built in to the HTTP protocol for exactly this type of request. If the server you are talking to supports it, you can add a header to your request like this: `Range: bytes=0-4096` to get the first 4KB.

Comment: @GrantMcLean, Thank you, useful information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`on_body` is called repeatedly as chunks arrive. Returning false from `on_body` terminates the download.

```
sub my_http_request {
   my $cb = pop;
   my ($method, $url, %args) = @_;

   croak("Unsupported: on_body")          if $args{on_body};
   croak("Unsupported: want_body_handle") if $args{want_body_handle};

   my $max_to_read = delete($args{max_to_read});

   my $data;
   return http_request(
      $method => $url,
      %args,
      on_body => sub {
         #my ($chunk, $headers) = @_;
         $data .= $_[0];
         return !defined($max_to_read) || length($data) < $max_to_read;
      },
      sub {
         my (undef, $headers) = @_;
         $cb->($data, $headers);
      },
   );
}
```

---

Use `my_http_request` just like `http_request`, except it accepts an optional `max_to_read` parameter.

For example,

```
my $cb = AnyEvent->condvar();
my_http_request(
   GET => 'http://...',
   ...
   max_to_read => ...,
   $cb,
);

my ($data, $headers) = $cb->recv();
```

For example,

```
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar();
my_http_request(
   GET => 'http://...',
   ...
   max_to_read => ...,
   sub {
      my ($data, $headers) = @_;
      ...
      $done->send();
   },
);

$done->recv();
```

Comment: I meant to make `max_to_read` optional. Fixed. Also removed comment for code that was removed, and made parameter order consistent with the original function.